# Moving Average in PowerBI

Tags: statistics, powerbi, dax

I have a dataset where everyday users answer question from a forum if the answer was usefull or not.

So I compute:

```
- a measure that calculate the total answer by yes: answerYes
- a measure that calculate the total answer (yes or no): answerTot
- a measure that calculate the ratio: answerPercYes= DIVIDE(answerYes,answerTot)
```

What I need is to compute a moving average over my date dimension (answerDate) on 7 days. How can I accomplish this in PowerBI?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
movingAverage:=
    CALCULATE(
        [answerPercYes]
       ,DATESINPERIOD(
          'answerDate'[Date]
          ,max('answerDate'[Date])
          ,-7
          ,DAY
        )
     )
```